# Deselect a TableItem after clicking in an empty slot in the table

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, swt

I have a table with many TableItems (Not a tableViewer), when I click on one of the table Items it get selected . The only way to deselect it is by selecting another TableItem. I want to implement a way to deselect The Table selection when The user click on the table Where there is no TableItems, or when ReSelecting the same TableItem.

```
table.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {

            if(e.item != ItemSelectioner ) {
                ItemSelectioner = (TableItem)e.item;
                // Blabla
            }else {
                ItemSelectioner = null;
                table.deselectAll();
                //blabla

            }



        }
    });
```

As you can see, am using a selectionEvent which I think is the probleme, and using:

```
e.doit = false;
```

didn't work also.

Answer (score 1):

Selection events are not generated for the empty parts of the table so you can't use a selection listener to do this.

You can use a mouse down listener and check if there is a table item at the mouse location:

```
table.addListener(SWT.MouseDown, event -> {

    TableItem item =  table.getItem(new Point(event.x, event.y));

    if (item == null) {   // No table item at the click location?
      table.deselectAll();
    }
 });
```

To clear the selection the second time an item is clicked use something like this:

```
table.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener()
  {
    private int lastSelected = -1;

    @Override
    public void handleEvent(final Event event)
    {
      final int selectedIndex = table.getSelectionIndex();

      if (selectedIndex < 0) {
        lastSelected = -1;
        return;
      }

      if (selectedIndex == lastSelected) {
        table.deselect(selectedIndex);

        lastSelected = -1;
      }
      else {
        lastSelected = selectedIndex;
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks , that worked perfectly . But still , I want to be able to deselect the Item when I reClick on it :
=======================================================
    table.addListener(SWT.MouseDown, event -> {

      TableItem item =  table.getItem(new Point(event.x, event.y));

      if (item == ItemSelectioner || item == null) { 
        table.deselectAll();
        ItemSelectioner = null;
      }else {
       ItemSelectioner = item;
      }
   });
========================================
I used this code but still, it doesn't work :/

Comment: @Med-AmineBenyettou Added a selection listener to do that.

Comment: @greg-449 The selection listener does not seem to work for me (Windows 10). The item in the end stays selected.

Comment: @LorisSecuro I have changed the code to just use the selection index. I don't have Windows so can't test on that.

Comment: @greg-449 Still doesn't work. I've tried myself many combinations but nothing works. It seems that there is some async action going on that re-select the item after the deselection.

Comment: @LorisSecuro You could try setting `event.doit = false` or using `Display.asyncExec` to run the `table.deselect` after the event.

Comment: event.doit doesn't work , What I noticed is that SWT launches some kin of an unvisible event when we click on an Item in a table .Even if the code we are writing is correct , another line that is automatique launches and reselect the Item . Actually that was my firrst probleme but I couldnt fix it with event.doit = false :/

Comment: `table.getDisplay().asyncExec(() -> table.deselect(selectedIndex));`  for the deselect line might work since it will delay the deselect until after the event.